# How can I export a list of modules with my own module?

Tags: perl

I want to create a Base class that exports the following modules everytime I use it:

```
use 5.018;
use Data::Dumper;
use Warning; 
#etc etc
```

**Similar questions:**

- (2017) [Shortcut to import modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42126154/2173773)
- (2016) [Perl import into all my packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40953539/2173773)
- (2015) [How to load a bunch of perl modules into a perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28714502/2173773)
- (2013) [Is there any way to “auto-use” certain modules everytime I write a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504478/is-there-any-way-to-auto-use-certain-modules-everytime-i-write-a-script)
- (2012) [How to include a file that contains all the required Perl module names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393144/how-to-include-a-file-that-contains-all-the-required-perl-module-names)
- (2011) [How to “use” multiple modules with one “use”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491058/how-to-use-multiple-modules-with-one-use)
- (2011) [How to make “use My::defaults” with modern perl & utf8 defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412799/perl-how-to-make-use-mydefaults-with-modern-perl-utf8-defaults)
- (2011) [Explanation how to works the “uni::perl” module - loading pragmas and other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494138/perl-explanation-how-to-works-the-uniperl-module-loading-pragmas-and-othe)
- (2011) [How to share the import of a large list of modules between many independent scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919625/perl-how-to-share-the-import-of-a-large-list-of-modules-between-many-independen)
- (2010) [How do I group my package imports into a single custom package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467819/how-do-i-group-my-package-imports-into-a-single-custom-package)
- (2009) [Is there a way to “use” a single file that in turn uses multiple others in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437785/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-single-file-that-in-turn-uses-multiple-others-in-perl)

Answer (score 6):

Try out the CPAN module [ToolSet](https://metacpan.org/pod/ToolSet).

**Other similar CPAN modules:**

- (2015) [perl5i](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i)
- (2015) [strictures](https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures)
- (2015) [Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Modern::Perl)
- (2014) [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into)
- (2012) [uni::perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mons/uni-perl-0.92/perl.pm.PL)
- (2011) [common::sense](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MLEHMANN/common-sense-3.4/sense.pm.PL)
- (2011) [rig](https://metacpan.org/pod/rig)
- (2010) [Acme::Very::Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Acme::Very::Modern::Perl)
- (2009) [latest](https://metacpan.org/pod/latest)
- (2005) [Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Toolkit)
- (2001) [Pollute::Persistent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pollute::Persistent)

Comment: string eval is not per se bad. You just shouldn't use it in a performance-critical loop and have to be somewhat more careful to not create syntax errors in the eval'ed code.