# Perl: How can I inject the UTF-8 pragma in a boilerplate module?

Tags: perl, utf-8, perl-module

I have a Perl boilerplate module similar to [common::sense](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/common-sense/sense.pod) or [Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Modern::Perl).
It's roughly a rip off of Modern::Perl. It looks like this (shortened to keep this question concise):

```
package Prologue;

use strict;
use feature  ();
use utf8;

sub import {
    strict  ->import;
    feature ->import( ':5.20', 'signatures' );
    utf8    ->import;
}
1;
```

All in all this works fine. Except for the UTF-8 pragma. Manually adding `use utf8;` in the calling code has the desired effect.

So how can I inject the UTF-8 pragma into the calling code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Just switching on `utf8;` by default isn't as simple as it sounds.

Comment: I want `use utf8;` so I can use non ASCII chars in variable names (german umlauts in my case). I do admit, that I have not understood [the world of unicode in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/1975049) in its entirety.

Comment: This might be relevant reading then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default

Comment: Shame on me... I had a typo in `use ProLogue;`. I am on Windows, which is case insensitive and did not report the error. Should this question better be deleted?

Comment: @patszim It actually can't be deleted because it's got an upvoted answer. I would make your last comment an answer in the off chance that someone else in the future has a similar issue.

Comment: See [How can I export a list of modules with my own module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814892/how-can-i-export-a-list-of-modules-with-my-own-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me.

```
$ cat Prologue.pm
package Prologue;
require utf8;
sub import { utf8->import }
1;

$ cat a.pl
$_ = "é";
CORE::say(sprintf("%vX", $_));
use Prologue;
$_ = "é";
CORE::say(sprintf("%vX", $_));

$ perl a.pl
C3.A9
E9
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Self-answered by [patszim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975049/patszim))*

[As pointed out by ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745346) this does work as expected. My failure was a typo in the `use` statement: `use ProLogue;` with a capital "L" instead of `use Prologue;`. On my case-insensitive Windows system this causes Perl to silently not import the Prologue module.

The silent import failure on Windows now has a [bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126167).

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a direct answer but a pointer for people trying to create their own boilerplate modules.*

The [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into) module can import arbitrary modules into other packages. It has a very good explanation of what can go wrong and what to do about it: [Why to use this module?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into#WHY-USE-THIS-MODULE) I myself did not use that module but copied the respective tricks into my boilerplate module.